# 32 bit Access database 64 bit Win 7 dev-server

Tags: asp.net, iis, ms-access, windows-7

Win 7 Pro 64 bit, IIS 7, Access database (32bit) to be used with the web I am upgrading.  Used odbcad32.exe and created DSN.  Web site still does not access the database.  I am thinking that the IIS 7 on a Win 7 64 bit system is 64 bit correct? I have turned on 32 bit Application Pool in IIS to true.  Not sure what else to do, any help would be great.

Comment: You'll need to provide a little bit more information, please. What exactly is the error that you are receiving? Also, I am assuming this is asp.net?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the response.  The error is:"Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

/meetings/level1mtng.inc, line 17 "